# decimal data type in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g

My database table contains one column of `varchar2(20,10)`, but since it is a total amount field I need currency data type.  (If I enter 1235.5 it should take it as 1235.50.)

I tried changing to type `number(20,2)`, I am not able to do this with number(20,2) in Oracle 10g.

Comment: What happens when you try? Btw, are you sure `VARCHAR2(20,10)` is even a valid type?

Comment: I am 100% sure your table does ***not*** contain a column defined as `varchar2(20,10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need not bother about insert, as long you have a precision of atleast 2. When you are fetching using select query, try using the select query as :

```
Select to_char(1234.4, 'fm9999999.00') from dual; 
Select to_char(1234.45, 'fm9999999.00') from dual; 
Select to_char(1234,'fm9999999.00') from dual;
Select to_char(1234.4567, 'fm9999999.00') from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you Nisha, It is working to select that coloumn value. But it would be great if i can alter the table coloumn data type in such a way that it should always generate value by abending '0'.

Comment: @MadhuCapgemini: Currency need not always have the second precision digit as 0. For example, INR can have any decimal value from 0.00 to .99. Hence it is not advisable to append 0